# Can't replicate cURL request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, syntax

I can make the request I want using cURL, but it's failing when I try to replicate it using Laravel (returning 404). I've ensured the data being sent is identical.

Here's the cURL:

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://www.api-provider.com/api/v2/access_keys \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 53d9814ed1385f44e6d5ed24979e11c2f7da654b40' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"access_key":{"key":"Lmy48Z0vA89","rate_ids":["[]"],"listing_id":"5de8f56797209ffbe","quantity":1,"is_active":true}}'
```

Here's the Laravel equivalent (following [Guzzle's documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json)):

```
$response = Http::retry(3, 100)->withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer 53d9814ed1385f44e6d5ed24979e11c2f7da654b40',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
])->post('https://www.api-provider.com/api/v2/access_keys',[
    'json' => [
        'access_key' => [
            'key' => "Lmy48Z0vA89", 
            'listing_id' => "5de8f56797209ffbe",
            'rate_ids' => [
            ],
            'quantity' => 1,
            'is_active' => true,
        ]
    ],
]);
```

The endpoint, ids and authorization tokens are fake for SO, but assume they're correct and working over cURL and then dropped into the Laravel version.

Given the request works over cURL I assume the error is purely syntax? I've tried debugging and seeing what's being sent to the API to compare, but Laravel isn't showing me the payload even when `withOptions(['debug' => true])` is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = Http::retry(3, 100)->withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer 53d9814ed1385f44e6d5ed24979e11c2f7da654b40',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
])->post('https://www.api-provider.com/api/v2/access_keys',[
        'access_key' => [
            'key' => "Lmy48Z0vA89", 
            'listing_id' => "5de8f56797209ffbe",
            'rate_ids' => [
            ],
            'quantity' => 1,
            'is_active' => true,
        ]
]);
```

Do you really need binding as json array 'json' => [access-key ...]

Comment: I was following the Guzzle documentation (https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json) but you appear to be right! Thanks.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data
Here is the part i guess to follow :)

Comment: I did read that, but there's nothing about json in there.